Constructing a system of two cubic polynomial equations with exactly 9 real solutions in Maple
I am trying to construct a system of two cubic polynomial equations in two variables (x and y) with exactly 9 real solutions using Maple. However, I am having trouble finding the appropriate coefficients for the polynomials to ensure exactly 9 real solutions.
Here is the system
$$ a_1 x^3 + a_2 x^2 y + a_3 x y^2 + a_4 x^2 + a_5 xy + a_6 y^2 + a_7 x + a_8 y =0 $$
$$ b_1 x^3 +b_2 y^3 + b_3 x^2 y + b_4 x y^2 + b_5 x^2 + b_6 xy + b_7 y^2 + b_8 x + b_9 y =0 $$
I would appreciate any guidance on how to construct such a system, ensuring exactly 9 real solutions with $x$ non-negative. Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated!
I have also posted this question on MSE (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4951785/constructing-a-system-of-two-cubic-polynomial-equations-with-exactly-9-real-solu).

Gerald Edgar suggested, but deleted,
using $(x-1)(x-2)(x-3) = (y-1)(y-2)(y-3) = 0$.
One could more generally use any independent linear combinations
of two such polynomials; or more interesting, start from such a system
(or translate to the simpler-looking $x^3-x = y^3-y = 0$)
and deform a bit so the solutions are real but not obvious.

@NoamD.Elkies: I started with $x^3-x = y^3-y = 0$, then noticed the condition $x$ non-negative.  Also, it seems the first one has no $y^3$ term.

@GeraldEdgar   I see.  But now I also see that neither equation
has a constant term, so $(0,0)$ is automatically a solution.
OK, use $x(x-1)(x-2) = y^3 - y = 0$,
and optionally deform without making the solutions
$(0,\pm 1)$ go to the left of the $y$-axis.

Crossposted from MSE, where he received  enough hints in comments

okay thanks, I'll try. I've also noticed that $(0,0)$ is already one of the solutions. Someone suggested taking a cubic in $x$ with distinct real roots and the same for $y$ and then making the coupled equations through the linear transformation $x+y=X, x-y=Y$.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4951785/constructing-a-system-of-two-cubic-polynomial-equations-with-exactly-9-real-solu

Is it bad to crosspost?

If so, I apologize I'm new here.

In general it is considered good etiquette to wait at least a couple of days after one posts on math.SE, and then mention the original question if one does crosspost. This avoids unnecessary duplicate work.
